# Django QuerySet: filter by 'value LIKE column'

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have an SQL query to determine the longest matching prefix matching a given input string. The use case is to find the rate to call a given destination, which is determine by multiple rows in database. The most specific matching prefix is the one to use.

So in raw SQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM rateplan_rates
WHERE '3212345789' LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%')
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(prefix) DESC LIMIT 1
```

In the above example, the destination is 3212345789. In the real application this is backed by caching mechanisms and more stuff, but it comes down to that.

I want to accomplish the same in our Django project for an API call, and I'm aware that I can use raw SQL there too, but I was wondering if there was a way to do in Django "queryset-language".

I'm stuck with this:

```
RateplanRate.objects \
    .annotate(prefix_length=Length('prefix'), prefix_match=Concat('prefix', '%')) \
    .filter('search_value LIKE prefix_match') \
    .order_by('-prefix_length')[0:1]
```

The missing part is the `search_value LIKE prefix_match` of course. Is this possible or should I just fall back to raw SQL?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) or [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains)

E.g.

```py
RateplanRate.objects.filter(field__icontains='foobar')
```

Comment: But here you wrap it the other way around, the idea is that the `prefix` field should be the prefix of the value (`'foobar'`).

Comment: Exactly, I need 'foobar__icontains=field', you could say.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly but have a look at [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/) which might be useful to you.

Comment: @HigorRossato: the operands need to be swapped, it is not `field LIKE value`, but `value LIKE field`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

we need to add an extra() filter for something like this

```
RateplanRate.objects.extra(select={'prefix_length':'prefix.length', }).extra(where=["%s LIKE concat(prefix,'%%')"], params=[search_value]).order_by('-prefix_length')
```